# Screen Width Javascript does not work on all Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, tablet, screen-orientation

I'm new to Javascript programming. Basically, I want to replace the text, when the screen width goes to 900px and below. Due to the Javascript code of the responsive tabs, I cannot use CSS to hide the longer words.

The Javascript code I've applied, normally works well on all desktop browsers and iOS browsers. However, I can't get it to work on all Android browsers or devices apart from Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1.

These are the screenshots:
http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/5fed3f8c9c15c542ff10816861954097d2f36d53

Following is the Javascript code. I'm not sure if I'm missing anything else here?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 900) {
        $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Score');
        $('li.hwh').text('How we help');
    } else {
        $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Credit Score');
        $('li.hwh').text('How we help people');
    }
}
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

And this is the HTML code for reference.

```html
      <ul class="resp-tabs-list"> 
        <li class="tab-title">Learn about credit</li>
        <li class="tab-title cvc">Credit Report vs Credit Score</li>
        <li class="tab-title hwh">How we help people</li>
        <li class="tab-title">Company news</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: I don't know. But I usually write $(window).resize(function(){checkWidth()});

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be better if you used media queries with `window.matchMedia`. Here is a general example:

```
;(function(root) {
  'use strict';

  var width900;
  var doc = root.document;

  function changeBackground() {
    if(this.matches) {
      doc.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else {
      doc.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
  }

  if(root.matchMedia) {
    width900 = root.matchMedia('(max-width: 900px)');
  }

  root.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
    if(width900) {
      changeBackground.call(width900);
    }
  }, false);
}(this));
```

For Browsers that don't support `matchMedia` natively you can use a polyfill: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js

You can read more about `matchMedia` here: 
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. I've never implemented the above solutions but my Javascript code apparently works! I just have to delete touche.js because it comes in conflict with anything that requires "tapping" the link or element. Cheers!